# Archived versions of Mongo are .exe and not .msi, how do you install them?

Tags: mongodb, windows

I'm looking to start experimenting with mongoDB at my company, but the only approved version is an older version (6.0.3). You can download this version on Mongo's website [link to the archived 6.0.3 for Windows](https://fastdl.mongodb.org/windows/mongodb-windows-x86_64-6.0.3.zip), but it gives you a .zip with executables for mongod and mongos, and a powershell script for compass.

I was going to install mongoDB as a Windows service, but even with the instructions on their website, I am completely lost. I have .exe's, not a .msi as every tutorial shows.

I apologize for the extremely noob question, but how do I get started installing and configuring from the .exes?

I downloaded the approved 6.0.3, and was expecting to have .msi installers so I could install MongoDB as a service. Instead I have .exe executables which I am struggling to make use of.

Comment: Why only 6.0.3. Current version 6.0.6 is just a minor release with only a few bug fixes. Have a look at [mongod.exe](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/program/mongod.exe/), you can use `--install` to create the service. Or have a look at https://github.com/Wernfried/mongoDB-oneclick

Comment: Thanks Wernfried. We will give that a shot at work. Can't believe it was that obvious and couldn't find anything about it when I was parsing the documentation/searching online.